# What does it mean for a form to have a meromorphic extension?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In the article "a remark on a non-vanishing theorem of P. Deligne and G. D. Mostow." by Esnault and Viehweg, they consider the following setup. $X$ is an $n$-dimensional smooth complex manifold, and $D\subset X$ is a normal crossings divisor. We denote $U=X\setminus D$. We have a form $\omega\in H^0(U,\Omega_U^n\otimes L)$, for some rank 1 local system $L$ on $U$. The condition they need is then that $\omega$ has a meromorphic extension to $X$. They don't define what this means though?

My guess is that it means that if we take a general point $p\in D_i$, a component of $D$, and coordinates $x_1,\dots,x_n$ in which $D_i=\{x_1=0\}$, that we can then write
$$\omega = \frac{f}{x_1^m}dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n \otimes e,$$
where $e$ is a multivalued section of $L$ around $p$, $f$ is holomorphic, and $m$ is some integer. Is this indeed the meaning?

Comment: That sounds right.

Comment: @DonuArapura thanks. Does that mean that this condition is automatic if all objects involved are analytifications of algebraic ones?

Comment: @DonuArapura e.g. $\omega=f^q\psi$ with $q$ a rational number, and $\psi,f$ algebraic

Comment: The point is avoid sections with essential singularities. These could arise even if the bundles come form algebraic ones.

Comment: @DonuArapura If you write this as an answer I can accept it and the question can be marked as answered.